# OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter bean creation fails with MalformedParameterizedTypeException

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am using 1.0.0.RELEASE version of spring-security-oauth2. My Maven dependency is :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

This is the bean definition I have in my application context.

```
<bean id="inMemoryTokenStore"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore">
</bean>

<bean id="tokenServices"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="inMemoryTokenStore" />
</bean>

<bean id="oAuth2AuthenticationManager"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationManager">
    <property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices" />
</bean>

<bean id="oAuth2AuthProcessingFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="oAuth2AuthenticationManager" />
    <qualifier value="oAuth2"/>
</bean>
```

When I try to create bean, I get the following weird exception with no specific information.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'oAuth2AuthProcessingFilter' defined in class path resource [com/etrade/spring/security/oauth/web/application/OAuth2Filters-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:103)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(DelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:228)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.validateConstructorArguments(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:42)
at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.<init>(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:35)
at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:77)
at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeParameterizedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:86)
at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:122)
at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:31)
at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ConstructorRepository.getParameterTypes(ConstructorRepository.java:76)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericParameterTypes(Method.java:282)
at org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.getTargetType(GenericTypeResolver.java:65)
at org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.resolveParameterType(GenericTypeResolver.java:80)
at org.springframework.beans.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.getWriteMethodParameter(GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.java:150)
at org.springframework.beans.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.getPropertyType(GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.java:132)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.isExcludedFromDependencyCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1269)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.filterPropertyDescriptorsForDependencyCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1101)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
... 41 more
```

I read similar issues on Stackoverflow and tried suggestions like verifying that there is no spring version conflict but nothing helped. Please let me know how this could be fixed.

Comment: There was no spring version conflict but there was conflict in spring security version. One of the dependencies used Spring Security 3.0.7.RELEASE version. After upgrading it to use 3.1.3.RELEASE version of Spring security, issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd shed some light on the issue, since I'm digging through this as well.

If we look at [OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/1.0.4.RELEASE/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/authentication/OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java), it sets the type of `authenticationDetailsSource` as `AuthenticationDetailsSource<HttpServletRequest, ?>`, but that wasn't templated until at least version 3.1.0.M1 (See [SEC-1486](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1486) and [source on github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationDetailsSource.java)).

The short of it is, spring-security-oauth *needs* 3.1.x of spring security to work. I'll be attempting a messy workaround until we can upgrade it, since we're relying on a grails plugin that requires 3.0.x.